# h:selectOneMenu in loop

Tags: jsf

I want to remember values from multiple h:selectOneMenu component in c:forEach loop. Now only last value from h:selectOneMenu is remember. I don't know how many h:selectOneMenu will appear.

```
<h:panelGrid 
                    id="wynik"
                    columns="2"
                    border="0" 
                    cellpadding="2" 
                    cellspacing="0" 
                    rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" 
                    rules="all" 
                    style="border:solid 1px">
                    <h:outputText id="ns" value="Numer stanowiska"/>
                    <h:outputText id="kontr" value="Kontroler"/>
                    <c:forEach 
                        var="stanowisko"
                        begin="1" 
                        end="#{stojakiController.selected.iloscstanowisk}"
                        step="1">
                        <h:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{stanowisko}"/>
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:selectOneMenu 
                                id="kontroler_#{stanowisko}" 
                                value="#{wyposazenieStojakaController.selected.kontroler}" 
                                title="#{bundle.CreateWyposazenieStojakaTitle_kontroler}" 
                                required="true" 
                                requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateWyposazenieStojakaRequiredMessage_kontroler}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{kontroleryController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </h:column>
                    </c:forEach>
                </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Could you share the source code?

Answer (score 4):

This is not the right way to render a table based on a dynamically sized collection. You're binding the value of each row to **one and same** backing bean property. This property would get overwritten every time whenever each row needs to set the value. That's why you end up with only the value of the last row.

You should be using `<h:dataTable>` instead, not a `<h:panelGrid>` with a `<c:forEach>`. You should be preparing a collection of concrete model objects, not only the size of objects. For example,

```
public class Item {

    private String value;

    // ...
}
```

Then, in the (post)constructor of the backing bean you should prepare as many as necessary.

```
public class Bean {

    private List<Item> items;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        for (int i = 0; i < yourDesiredAmountOfItems; i++) {
            items.add(new Item());
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

And here's a basic kickoff example how you should use it:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.value}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableValues}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

When you submit the form, JSF will set the value of each row rightly in each separate item object associated with the row.