# Several select menus with a4j support, only the last one works

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have several forms like this on the same page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{collectionBean.selectedCollection}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{collectionBean.collectionItems}" />
        <a4j:support event="onchange" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <a4j:commandButton value="Add" action="#{collectionBean.addToCollection(_resource)}" >
    </a4j:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Here is my Bean:

```
@Name("collectionBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
public class CollectionBean {
    private String selectedCollection;

    public String getSelectedCollection() {
        return selectedCollection;
    }

    public void setSelectedCollection(String collectionName) {
        selectedCollection = collectionName;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getCollectionItems() {
        ...
    }

    public void addToCollection(Resource res) {
        ...
    }
}
```

A form is associated to a resource `_resource`, its goal is to let the user add the resource to a collection he choses.

The problem is that only the last form on the page works: when changing the selection in the other forms, the `setSelectedCollection` method is never called.

Do you have an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that you've multiple components in a single view which each bind to one and same bean property? How does that make sense? Wouldn't you rather bind them to a separate bean property so that you can grab the individual values?

Comment: It is a table of resources, for each of these resources the user can select a collection in which to add the resource. I did not show the code here, but there is also an "add" button in the form.

Comment: It look more and more like that your problem has the same cause which is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972284/hselectonemenu-in-loop/10973440#10973440 You're binding multiple components to a single bean property and somehow expecting that this single property can magically hold multiple values at once.

Comment: I guess that is the reason why it does not work. But I want to use this form as a "widget", in different locations. In that case, is there any way to use this `selectOneMenu` without a Bean property, simply call a method with the selected value as a parameter?

Comment: Do you understand the concrete problem? You seem to not understand the problem, as the answer is rather obvious if you understand the problem. You were attempting to bind multiple values to a single `String`. This ain't ever going to work, it simply doesn't make any sense. You just need a `String[]` or `List<String>` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972284/hselectonemenu-in-loop/10973440#10973440) and in the comments, it does not make sense to bind several components to the same bean property. So I used a Map in the backing bean, with the resource id as a key.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{collectionBean.selections[_resource.id]}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{collectionBean.collectionItems}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Still, it did not fix the main problem: only the last form on the page worked. For all the other forms, the method `getSelections` was never called.

Then, instead of using several forms (one form for each select menu), I used a single englobing form. I don't know why, but it worked...

Comment: *only the last form on the page worked* that's normal HTML behavior, only a single form can be submitted per request. *Then, instead of using several forms (one form for each select menu), I used a single englobing form* based in the last statement, this was a possible solution for your problem.

Comment: By the way, in this cases you should not make the bean session scoped, instead view scoped. In CDI, this can be achieved using [MyFaces CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/).

Comment: Maybe, but nothing prevents us to have several forms on the same page and to submit them independently.
For the scope you are right, but I also use this bean for other things which require a session scope. In addition, it is not that unpleasant to keep the previous selections when refreshing the page.

Comment: As you said, nothing prevents you for have more than 1 form in a single page, but the problem was to process more than 1 form in a single request, which can't be done :).